# Express: Remove charset=utf-8 from Content-Type "application/json; charset=utf-8"

Tags: node.js, json, rest, express

I have a NodeJS and express based app. Every time I m trying to fetch a response, I m getting `Content-Type: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`. I m unable to parse this on front end as I m expecting response with header `Content-Type: "application/json"`.

I have tried `res.setHeader, res.set` methods as well but nothing seems to be helpful. Any advice is appreciated.

Following is my express code:

```
const app = express();

configureMongoClient();

app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.options('*', cors())

app.use("/api-docs", swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocument));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, POST');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, X_BPI_CONTEXT');
    res.header("Content-Type", "application/json")
    next();
});
app.use("/users", usersRouter);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
```

My Front end call is as follow:

```
fetch(uri, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Content-Type: "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(requestData),
  })
    .then((response) => {
      debugger;
      return response.json()
    }) .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Express will set the charset for you. So if you want to bypass it, don't use express methods, since `res` extends from: `http.ServerResponse` you can use `.writeHeader` & `.write`.

> The res object is an enhanced version of Node’s own response object
> and supports all built-in fields and methods.

```
res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
res.write(JSON.stringify(object))
res.end()
```

In any case, it's better to add the charset, and I suggest you do the changes in the front end instead.

Comment: I have added the frontend call as well. Can you tell me what to modify to get the proper result i.e. to be able to read data from response as JSON ?

Comment: With that call, you can read the data as JSON without any problem. What error are you getting?
I suppose you don't have: `{ headers: { Content-Type: "application/json" } }` but `{ headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } }`

Comment: When making the call in postman m getting the data back as json but from the frontend the call is going through just no response. I get 200 success though but response is empty

Comment: hmm being honest, you probably have other error. Hard to say with what you show, Check the network tab of the browser, see if there are any errors in the console too. I need more information, because that request is correct, if it works in Postman it should work in the browser, unless you're getting a CORS error.

Comment: https://imgur.com/fjQexK0 this is how my console looks. I do have a CORS error. Thats weird because I have cors enabled on my app.

Comment: Then it's a CORS issue. Nothing to do with the charsrt