# How to set response as a PNG in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

I'm making an API in Node.js (Express) and are running into an issue with setting response headers.
I'm using `res.set('content-type', "image/png");` but when I enter dev tools it shows as `Content-Type: image/png; charset=utf-8`. How do I remove the `charset=utf-8`?

Here's the snippet of my code:

```
//res.set('content-type', "contentType");
res.set('content-type', "image/png");
console.log(response.headers)
return res.send(response.data);
```

(the `contentType` and `response.headers` are from a get request.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set content-type when doing res.send()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51661744/how-to-set-content-type-when-doing-res-send)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Express: Remove charset=utf-8 from Content-Type "application/json; charset=utf-8"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59449221/express-remove-charset-utf-8-from-content-type-application-json-charset-utf-8)

Answer (score 2):

As explained at https://stackoverflow.com/a/51661772/412529 , use

```js
res.setHeader('content-type', 'image/png');
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to deliver a `image/png` not plain text. When I set it to `image/png` it delivers it as utf-8.

Comment: my apologies, I copy/pasted the other solution without thinking. edited. the important part is `.setHeader` instead of `.set`